# jQuery fadeToggle element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div that contains two `<p>` elements and I am trying to toggle them with a click on another div, using a fade effect (has an initial CSS `display:none;`). But when I click the trigger div, despite the effect works, during the transition, both elements are visible, so one jumps under the other one, and only when the effect finishes, the other element is removed and the new visible one goes to the correct position. Basically I want the fade in part to start only when the fading out element is no longer "using space", so it fades in in the same place the other was. How can I solve that?

Here's my code:

JS:

```
$("span#contagem-fotos").click(function() {
    $("div.info-foto p").fadeToggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
ul#listagem-fotos li div.info-foto {
    padding:7px;
    height:14px;
    background-color:#300;
    position:relative;
}

ul#listagem-fotos li div.info-foto p.texto-ficheiro {
    font-size:0.80em;
    text-align:left;
    display:none;
}

ul#listagem-fotos li div.info-foto p.texto-numero {
    font-size:1em;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="info-foto">
    <p class="texto-numero"><?php echo sprintf("%04d", $db->SeekPosition()); ?></p>
    <p class="texto-ficheiro"><?php echo $row->filename; ?></p>
    <div data-imageid="<?php echo $row->image_id; ?>" class="fav-icon <?php echo $fav_class; ?>" title="Adicionar/remover favorito"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added an answer using your markup and no need for `positioning:absolute;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out...much better without positioning

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxdS4/3/)

[Fiddle Using Your Markup](http://jsfiddle.net/xxdS4/5/)

```
 $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").not('.hide').fadeToggle(function(){        
        $(".hide").fadeToggle(function(){
                $("p").addClass('hide');
                $(this).removeClass('hide');
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I would like to avoid that because of some other interfering CSS properties. Is there any way to start the fadeIn only when the fadeOut is complete?

Comment: Yeas there is...give me a sec

Comment: If your set on the fade, and don't want to do absolute positioning, you will have to do this with classes...

Comment: That new code is not working on mine, as it was supposed. Quite strange... It does the toggle, but without the effect... Bahhhhh...

Comment: Solved with absolute positioning. My problem with absolute was having the text centred. But I managed to find that by using left:0 and right:0, the text gets centred.

Comment: Well my original answer was to use `positioning:absolute;` so I should get an accepted answer, I have edited my answer in case you want to so it without positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use delay(milliseconds) like below:

```
var show_hide = function () {
    $("span#contagem-fotos").fadeToggle(callblack);
}

var callblack = function () {
    $("div.info-foto p").fadeToggle()
        .delay(500).queue(show_hide);
}
```

Comment: That will swap them twice, reverting to the original state. I need to delay the fadeIn effect inside the fadeToggle().

Comment: If you have room to avoid jquery transitions please try CSS3 [Transitions](http://hugoware.net/blog/using-css-transitions)